# Unity shows border of tiles during camera movement

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a texture atlas where every sprite is surrounded by a pink border. Each sprite is 15x15( 16x16 with the border) [image]

I imported the texture atlas and split it so that every tile would be 15x15 px in size, and drew up a Tilemap. Everything looks fine in the tile map, and everything looks file when standing still.

[image]

However, when the camera moves, I see the border in the opposite direction of whatever way the camera is moving (If I move up, the border appears on the bottom of some tiles, if I move left, the border appears on the right of some tiles).

[image]

Is there any way to stop this from happening?

Comment: Does this happen in a built or only in the editor?

Comment: is the border on all 4 sides? if so, your sprite isnt 15x15 and 16x16 with border, it would be either 15x15 and 17x17 or 14x14 and 16x16

Comment: i guess they are 17x17.

@derHugo I thought it only happened in the build, but it does happen in the editor if I am zoomed in. If I zoom out, the issue disappears.